# Better way to code One action for multiple classes

Tags: jquery

So I want to trigger a single action for the same classes. For example they click a button and an action will occur.  Is there a better way to code this? I have 12 events, do I need to add the same code over and over again for different classes until ctabtn11 and event12back and event12front?

```
    $('.ctabtn').on('click', function(){
    $('.event1back').show(); //this div will appear
    $('.event1front').remove(); //removes the div

}); 
    $('.ctabtn1').on('click', function(){
    $('.event2back').show();
    $('.event2front').remove(); //removes the div

}); 

$('.ctabtn2').on('click', function(){
    $('.event3back').show();
    $('.event3front').remove(); //removes the div

}); 

$('.ctabtn3').on('click', function(){
    $('.event4back').show();
    $('.event4front').remove(); //removes the div

});
```

Comment: It depends on how html is structured, can you provide html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not "same classes", try this.

```
<button data-ctabtn="1"></button>
...
<button data-ctabtn="12"></button>

$('[data-ctabtn]').on('click', function() {
    var idx = $(this).data('ctabtn');
    $('.event' + idx + 'back').show();
    $('.event' + idx + 'front').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write like below -

```
$('.ctabtn, .ctabtn1, .ctabtn2, .ctabtn3').on('click', function(){
    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    var num = 1;
    var lastChar = className.slice(-1);
    if(parseInt(lastChar)){
        num += parseInt(lastChar)
    }
    $('.event'+num+'back').show();
    $('.event'+num+'front').remove(); //removes the div

});
```